# How to parse this json in java? I want to fetch the keypad details that too with keypad id = 1,how can i achieve this?

Tags: java, json

{
    "Pump Details": {
        "Pump Configuration": "DUO",
        "Keypad": [{
            "Keypad AssetID ": 0,
            "Keypad SHASignature": null,
            "KeyPad Software Version": null,
            "Keypad CheckSum": null,
            "Keypad Unique ID": null,
            "Keypad FuelingPontID": "1",
            "Keypad ID": "1"
        }, {
            "Keypad AssetID ": 0,
            "Keypad SHASignature": null,
            "KeyPad Software Version": null,
            "Keypad CheckSum": null,
            "Keypad Unique ID": null,
            "Keypad FuelingPontID": "2",
            "Keypad ID": "2"
        }],
        "Cpu": [{
            "CpuAssetID ": 0,
            "CpuSHASignature": null,
            "CpuCheckSum": null,
            "CpuUnique ID": null,
            "CpuSoftware Version": null
        }],
        "Pump Serial Number": "194719471951",
        "Pulser": [{
            "Pulser Unique ID": null,
            "Pulser SHASignature": null,
            "Pulser Software Version": null,
            "Pulser AssetID ": 0,
            "Pulser ID": "1",
            "Pulser FuelingPontID": "1",
            "Pulser CheckSum": null
        }, {
            "Pulser Unique ID": null,
            "Pulser SHASignature": null,
            "Pulser Software Version": null,
            "Pulser AssetID ": 0,
            "Pulser ID": "2",
            "Pulser FuelingPontID": "2",
            "Pulser CheckSum": null
        }],
        "Display": [{
            "Display FuelingPontID": "1",
            "Display SHASignature": null,
            "Display CheckSum": null,
            "Display ID": "1",
            "Display Unique ID": null,
            "Display AssetID ": 0,
            "Display Software Version": null
        }, {
            "Display FuelingPontID": "2",
            "Display SHASignature": null,
            "Display CheckSum": null,
            "Display ID": "2",
            "Display Unique ID": null,
            "Display AssetID ": 0,
            "Display Software Version": null
        }]
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

You can make it with Gson liike that.(You make all object types.You should check parameter types.)

```
class Keypad{
@SerializedName("Keypad AssetID") public int AssetID;
@SerializedName("Keypad SHASignature") public String SHASignature;
@SerializedName("KeyPad Software Version") public String SoftwareVersion;
@SerializedName("Keypad CheckSum") public String CheckSum;
@SerializedName("Keypad Unique ID") public String UniqueID;
@SerializedName("Keypad FuelingPontID") public String FuelingPontID;
@SerializedName("Keypad ID") public String ID;
}
```